# Laravel 5.3.31 post method returning 405 method not allowed

Tags: post, laravel-5

I am getting '405 method not allowed' error when I try to send a post request using AngularJS http.post.

[image]

Below is my AngularJS code:

```
var headers = new Headers();

headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/user/authenticate-user',
                      JSON.stringify({"email": email, "password": password}),
                      {
                          headers: headers
                      }).map((response: Response) => {}
                    });
```

Below is my route in `web.php`...

```
Route::post('user/authenticate-user', 'UserController@postLogin');
```

I have written `postLogin` method in `UserController` controller.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a `}` just before the last `)` in your supplied code?

Answer (score 0):

just first simply check weather you reach at your route or not Route::post('user/authenticate-user', function(){
dd(Input::all());
});
it this will print all your sent data then check your function weather above it you mistakenly forgot to add ";" some where so he can't understand where you postLogin function start

think this will help you